# Swift '(int, int) -> $T4' is not identical to 'Point'

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm fairly new to swift and get this error. All I want the declaration to do is assign the 4 values to create 2 Point objects for a Line object. So Line(10, 20, 20, 40) should create two points at (10,20) and (20,40). But I get the error '(Int, Int) -> $T4' is not identical to 'Point'

```
class Point {
var x: Int = 0
var y: Int = 0

init(){
    x = 0
    y = 0
}

init(x: Int, y: Int) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  }
}

class Line: Point {
var pointA: Point
var pointB: Point

init(p1x: Int, p1y: Int, p2x: Int, p2y: Int) {
    self.pointA(p1x, p1y)
    self.pointB(p2x, p2y)
  }
}

var lineA = Line(p1x:10, p1y:20 , p2x:20 , p2y:40)
```

Comment: I believe you need to change your code in Line.init to         self.pointA = Point(x: p1x, y: p1y); self.pointB = Point(x: p2x, y: p2y) (and add a call to superclass initializer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in Line's `init` is meaningless. This is not valid Swift:

```
self.pointA(p1x, p1y)
self.pointB(p2x, p2y)
```

You can't just stick parentheses after the name of a variable like that! Plus you are not writing your `init` correctly. Here's a possible fix:

```
class Line: Point {
    var pointA: Point
    var pointB: Point

    init(p1x: Int, p1y: Int, p2x: Int, p2y: Int) {
        self.pointA = Point(x:p1x, y:p1y)
        self.pointB = Point(x:p2x, y:p2y)
        super.init()
    }
}
```

But as Antonio has already said, it all depends on what you're trying to do. My code above will cause your code to compile correctly, but I have no idea whether it does what you want, because what you're trying to do is utterly impossible to guess.

Answer (score 0):

In the initializer you are missing to create instances - you are just trying to reference 2 properties as if they were methods. The correct way is:

```
init(p1x: Int, p1y: Int, p2x: Int, p2y: Int) {
    self.pointA = Point(x: p1x, y: p1y)
    self.pointB = Point(x: p2x, y: p2y)
}
```

There is an architectural mistake though: `Line` inherits from `Point`, but I see no relationship between the 2 classes - you should at least call the superclass initializer, but what to pass?

I would instead define only 1 new property in `Line`, and reuse the property already available in `Point`:

```
class Line: Point {
    var pointB: Point

    init(p1x: Int, p1y: Int, p2x: Int, p2y: Int) {
        self.pointB = Point(x: p2x, y:p2y)
        super.init(x: p1x, y: p1y)
    }
}
```

I don't know if that makes sense (depending on what you want to achieve) - if not, then I would just make `Line` not inherit from `Point`. If you need a common interface, but with different implementations, then you can use a protocol adopted by the 2 classes.